# How do I survive until reinforcements arrive on Rendevous?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm still early in the campaign, and the only unit I can spawn from Larvae are Zerglings, which die en masse to the Hellions, Hellbats, and Firebats roving the map, and are utterly useless against the wraiths and vikings that appear, given that they can't attack air. Spore and Spine Crawlers help, but due to their size, they are out DPS'd by the Dominion forces, (especially once their mech starts rolling in).

Kerrigan is quite effective at halting their advance, but she is but one woman, and despite her constant utterances to the contrary, she is not a "one-woman army".

How can I hold out against the storms of fire and wings of death?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several failed attempts on the harder difficulties, I found out what I was doing wrong!

If you manage to rescue some of the zerg pinned down in the caves (the bonus objective), you'll receive more zerglings and some... queens?

Conventional wisdom dictates that Queens are strictly for use in macro and base management. After all, they're slow, and they have the ever-useful "Spawn Larvae" ability.

Except in the HotS Campaign, you have "Swarm Queens" instead. These look and act much like the multiplayer Queens, but with a couple of notable differences. First, they lack the spawn larvae ability. Additionally, they are *much* faster when not on creep relative to their multiplayer brethren, spawn creep tumor does not cost energy, and have "Rapid Transfusion" instead (smaller, heal over time, smaller cost, auto-cast).

As Swarm Queens are not considered a light unit (so no bonus damage from fire!) and, importantly, have the ability to attack air, they are the perfect unit to supplement your forces.

With their "Rapid Transfusion" ability, a small HoT that groups of queens will auto-cast on each other, you should be able to hold off most of the Domion's early assaults with a handful of queens, Kerrigan, and decent micro.

Unorthodox as it sounds, you are expected (and explicitly encouraged!) to use Queens to hold out until reinforcements arrive.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Using Queens for tanking and AA was certainly not unheard of in multiplayer though.

Comment: @OrcJMR Yeah, the difference here is, you need to use queens *offensively* as well (which got patched out via queen speed nerf)

Comment: Okay, that one was unorthodox, though creep-highway-able too :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this on Brutal quite easy.
A short and effective answer would be to add more Queens to your army, and have Karrigen focus down the Hellbats. The queens will auto-heal your Zerglings pretty effective.
Note that it is always a good idea to get at least one extra Hatchery - you can then build more queens and more units in general. This apply to all Zerg game-play and even throughout the campaign.